# Extract text from a div class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="prova.js"></script>
    <div class="altro"><a href=#>Div 1</a></div>    
    <div class="ann"><a href=#>Div 2</a></div>
    <div class="ann"><a href=#>Div 3</a></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to extract the content of the second div "Div 2" of the class "ann" using a JQuery script. I tried with:

```
var str = $( ".ann" ).text();
```

But it takes both Div 2 and Div 3. How can I extract only the one I want?

Comment: See here http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text from the first div with class "ann":

```
var str = $('.ann:first').text();
```

Or:

```
var str = $('.ann').eq(0).text();
```

But if you want the text inside the `<a>` element that is inside the first div with class "ann":

```
var str = $('.ann:first').children('a').text();
```

Or:

```
var str = $('.ann').eq(0).children('a').text();
```

Note:
- The `:first` selector limits the selector to the first matching element.
- The `.eq()` function reduces the matching set to the element with the given zero-based index.

Comment: `I would like to extract the content of the second div "Div 2" of the class "ann"` may be this will light the question to you.

Comment: @Jai - I took that to mean the OP wanted the div with content "Div 2", which is the second of the three divs, but the first one with class "ann".

Answer (score 2):

use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - it takes 0 based index

```
var str = $( ".ann" ).eq(1).text();
```

or [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
var str = $( ".ann:eq(1)" ).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `:not(:first)`:

```
var str = $(".ann:not(:first)").text();
```

or

```
var str = $(".ann").not(':first').text();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sDgG/)